# Jade variable rendering inside tag specifications

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a Jade page like so:

```
table
    th Site Name
    th Deadline
    th Delete Transaction

    - if (transactions != null)
        each item in transactions
            tr
                td= item.item_name
                td
                    span(id='countdown' + item.timeout + ')= item.timeout
                td
                    span(style='cursor: pointer;', onclick='deleteTransaction("=item.uniqueId")')= "X"

            button(id='confirmButton', onclick='confirm();')Confirm
```

As you can see in both the `span` attribute I try to put a local variable in two different ways and it doesn't work. Concerning the first way, I receive a `token ILLEGAL` error, while the second simply writes in my JavaScript something like `deleteTransaction("=item.uniqueId");`. I know the answer is something really stupid, but again and again Jade doc (even if it has improved) doesn't help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote [the docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade):

> Suppose we have the user local `{ id: 12, name: 'tobi' }` and we wish to create an anchor tag with `href` pointing to "/user/12" we could use regular javascript concatenation:
>
> ```
> a(href='/user/' + user.id)= user.name
> ```

Ergo:

```
span(id='countdown' + item.timeout)= item.timeout

// ...

span(style='cursor: pointer;', onclick='deleteTransaction("' + item.uniqueId + '")')= "X"
```

Quoting again:

> or we could use jade's interpolation, which I added because everyone using Ruby or CoffeeScript seems to think this is legal js..:
>
> ```
> a(href='/user/#{user.id}')= user.name
> ```

And so:

```
span(style='cursor: pointer;', onclick='deleteTransaction("#{item.uniqueId}")')= "X"
```

As a general tip that you'll use every day of your programming life: balance your quotes. Just like brackets and parentheses, every quotation mark must either open a new quotation or close an already-open quotation (of the same kind, i.e. double-quotes close double-quotes, single-quotes close single-quotes). To borrow your code:

```
span(id='countdown' + item.timeout + ')= item.timeout
  //                                 ^
  //                                 |
  // What's this guy doing? ---------+
```

Even though Jade is a templating language and perhaps not a "real" programming language this rule, just as in HTML (also not a programming language), will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks, I think I read correctly the spec and indeed, I did something really messy in my code. I guess it's because I'm ill, I should stop working while being sick. Thanks again dude!

Comment: Yeah, drink some orange juice and take a long nap. Your brain needs rest too! :)